# Access C++ function declared without calling convention specified from Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I try to use a DLL whose two functions are:

```
__declspec(dllexport) LPCWSTR* MW_ListReaders(_ULONG Context, int* NumberOfReaders);

__declspec(dllexport) _ULONG MW_Connect(_ULONG Context, LPCWSTR ReaderName);
```

For use with Delphi, and for the MW_ListReaders function, I made the following statement

```
function MW_ListReaders(Context : int64; var NumberOfReaders : integer) : PWideChar; stdcall;
```

Not knowing much in C ++ and in addition, pointers, I am lost.

How can I use these two functions in Delphi?

Comment: They look like cdecl to me

Comment: As for how to call the functions, we can only guess. You need to read the docs.

Comment: I edited title, to make this question less useless

Comment: @Warren I don't think the calling convention is actually the big issue. Eventually the asker will want to know how to access the array of C strings that are returned.

Comment: Yeah, maybe.  My but that's an ugly DLL API.

Answer (score 3):

Your `MW_ListReaders()` function is declared incorrectly.

The default calling convention in C/C++ when no calling convention is specified is `__cdecl`, not `__stdcall`.

`MW_ListReaders()` is returning a **pointer to a pointer to a wide char** (which would be `PPWideChar` in Delphi), but you have declared it as returning a **pointer to a wide char** (`PWideChar`) instead.

`ULONG` is a 32bit unsigned integer, not a 64bit signed integer.

Try this instead:

```
function MW_ListReaders(Context: UInt32; var NumberOfReaders: Integer): PPWideChar; cdecl; external 'filename.dll';

function MW_Connect(Context: UInt32; const ReaderName: PWideChar): UInt32; cdecl; external 'filename.dll'
```

`UInt32` was added in Delphi 2009.  If you are using an older version, or just for good practice in general, you can (and should) use the `ULONG` or `ULONG32` type (and other types) that is in the `Windows` unit instead to maintain compatibility with the original C/C++ declarations:

```
uses
  ..., Windows;

type
  PLPCWSTR = ^LPCWSTR;

function MW_ListReaders(Context: ULONG; var NumberOfReaders: Integer): PLPCWSTR; cdecl; external 'filename.dll';

function MW_Connect(Context: ULONG; ReaderName: LPCWSTR): ULONG; cdecl; external 'filename.dll'
```

Comment: If possible, I would use the original type names (e.g. `ULONG`, `LPCWSTR`). If they are present in one of the Winapi units, they are defined correctly and there is no need to think if your conversion (e.g. `PChar` or `PWideChar` or whatever) is correct. This avoids errors.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: true enough. On the other hand, there is no existing type in Delphi for `LPCWSTR*`, so you would have to define one manually: `type PLPCWSTR = ^LPCWSTR;`  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `_ULONG` corresponds to 32-bit unsigned integer type (at least [for MS compilers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc953fe1(v=VS.120).aspx)).
And note using **P**PWideChar as result type.

Edit: calling convention changed to cdecl, default one, as David Heffernan noticed.

```
function MW_ListReaders(Context: Cardinal; var NumberOfReaders : integer): PPWideChar; cdecl;
function MW_Connect(Context: Cardinal; ReaderName: PWideChar): Cardinal; cdecl;
```

Comment: You missed the calling convention on second function. But it's cdecl according to code in Q.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I blindly pasted `stdcall` from question.